# Notification syncing issue between iPhone and Apple watch

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I am working on iOS app in which push notifications comes from web server. I do Apple watch configuration in Xcode by adding new target and make new Provisioning Profiles and use them in Xcode for Apple watch. When i test it some times notification appear on Apple watch some times on iPhone not on both. Any one help

Answer (score 0):

The OS determines which device to send the notification to based on a few different factors. Primarily, the Watch will only receive the notification if it is being worn – unless you turn off wrist detection – and the iPhone is locked.